# CakePHP and NearlyFreeSpeech.net

Tags: cakephp, nearlyfreespeech

How do I set AllowOverride on NearlyFreeSpeech.net? I'm trying to follow the instructions at [Within cakePHP, In my routes.php only the '/' (base path) works. Any other url is 404 page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450289/within-cakephp-in-my-routes-php-only-the-base-path-works-any-other-url-i) to resolve the problems described therein.

So far, I've had to do the following when moving out of a WAMP development environment:

- Refer to controller names by their correct case
- Change the name of the server in the configuration file
- Add all the CakePHP-related files to the web group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

1. Copy the files over from your working environment (or do an export from your source control tool) into a new folder on NearlyFreeSpeech.net (NFS.net). Let's call the new folder "abc".
2. Import your database into NFS.net.
3. Configure database settings as necessary on the NFS.net version of the site.
4. Add the abc folder and everything in it to the web group.
5. Go into the .htaccess file in /home/public/abc and add "RewriteBase /abc" under "RewriteEngine on".
6. Add "RewriteBase /abc/app" to the .htaccess in /home/public/abc/app and add "RewriteBase /abc/app/webroot" to the one in /home/public/abc/app/webroot.