# Pretty (Mod_Rewrite) CakePHP URLs with NearlyFreeSpeech.net

Tags: php, cakephp, mod-rewrite, nearlyfreespeech

In [the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352642/cakephp-and-nearlyfreespeech-net), it was possible to get CakePHP working with NFS.net. Those instructions no longer work.

Right now, the default settings from NearlyFreeSpeech.net are MariaDB 10.1 and PHP Version 5.6.29. This meets the minimum requirements for the latest version of CakePHP 2.x.

Is it possible to install CakePHP into a subdirectory (e.g. "test"), follow the [tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html), set permissions (`chgrp -R web /home/public/test/app/tmp` and `chmod -R 775 /home/public/test/app/tmp`) go to http://www.example.com/test/posts/index, and add a blog post by clicking "add posts" on that page, entering "1234" as the title and body, and clicking the submit button?

What steps are required nowadays in addition to those listed in the documentation to make the [tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html) work?

I'd say that CakePHP works on NFS.net if you can:

1. Go to http://www.example.com/test/posts/index
2. Click the "add posts" link
3. Enter "1234" as the title and body
4. Clicking the submit button
5. See the new "1234" post.

This is what I see after following the instructions in the old StackOverflow post:

[image: Missing Controller error]

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you are using a wrong controller to for post action.... See the URL in the address bar

Confirm first that `Cake294Controller` exists by going to `/src/Controller/Cake294Controller.php`

If this file exists then it is something else...

Comment: Based on the URL, CakePHP should be looking for a controller named "PostsController", not "Cake294Controller".